# Height of \parbox can not be assigned with condition?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, etoolbox, dimensions, parbox

I want to assign the height of my `\parbox` with condition, as I did below, but fail. Why and how to deal with it?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}


\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\newdimen\ccc
\newdimen\bbb
\ccc20pt
\bbb30pt
\def\cond{0}
\newif\ifmycase

Case 1:\\%This case does not work, why?
\eappto\test{\noexpand\fbox{\noexpand\parbox[c][
  \ifcase\cond\relax \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax
  \or \ifmycase 1in\else 20pt\fi
  \fi
  ]
  {50pt}{aa}
}
}
\test\\

|\ifcase\cond 0\or 1\fi| % typeset 0 expected but nothing obtained,why?

Case 2:% This case does not work either, why?
\parbox[c][\ifnum 5 > 4 \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax\else 20pt\fi]{1in}{aa}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `\show\test` after the `\eappto` instruction, you will see

```
> \test=macro:
->\fbox {\parbox [c][ \relax \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb \relax ] {50pt}{aa} } .
```

which won't work because of the initial `\relax`. Where does it come from? You have

```
  \ifcase\cond\relax \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax
  \or \ifmycase 1in\else 20pt\fi
  \fi
```

so that's where you get it from. Removing the first `\relax` will now show

```
> \test=macro:
->\fbox {\parbox [c][ \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb \relax ] {50pt}{aa} } .
```

There is an unwanted spaces before `\dimexpr`, but that's not a problem; it comes from the unprotected endline in

```
\eappto\test{\noexpand\fbox{\noexpand\parbox[c][
```

that should be

```
\eappto\test{\noexpand\fbox{\noexpand\parbox[c][%
```

However, this is probably not what you really want, because the `\dimexpr` will use the values of `\aaa` and `\bbb` current when `\test` is called, not when the item has been added to it.

If you do

```
\eappto\test{%
  \noexpand\fbox{%
    \noexpand\parbox[c][%
      \ifcase\cond\space % case 0
        \the\dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax
      \or
        \ifmycase 1in\else 20pt\fi % case 1
      \fi
    ]
    {50pt}{aa}%
  }%
}
```

then you'll get

```
> \test=macro:
->\fbox {\parbox [c][50.0pt] {50pt}{aa}}.
```

which is more likely to be what you want. The `\space` will be gobbled when `\ifcase` is being evaluated, as `\cond` is a macro.

Why doesn't the following work?

```
\parbox[c][\ifnum 5 > 4 \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax\else 20pt\fi]{1in}{aa}
```

This is tougher. First:

```
% latex.ltx, line 11815:
\DeclareRobustCommand\parbox{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    \@iparbox
    {\@iiiparbox c\relax[s]}}%
```

You have a `[` following `\parbox`, so you get

```
\@iparbox[c][\ifnum 5 > 4 \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax\else 20pt\fi]{1in}{aa}
```

Now let's look at `\@iparbox`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 11819:
\def\@iparbox[#1]{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\@iiparbox{#1}}%
    {\@iiiparbox{#1}\relax[s]}}
```

You have `[`, so you get

```
\@iiparbox{c}[\ifnum 5 > 4 \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax\else 20pt\fi]{1in}{aa}
```

OK, what's `\@iiparbox`?

```
% latex.ltx, line 11823:
\def\@iiparbox#1[#2]{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\@iiiparbox{#1}{#2}}%
    {\@iiiparbox{#1}{#2}[#1]}}
```

There is no `[`, so we get

```
\@iiiparbox{c}{\ifnum 5 > 4 \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax\else 20pt\fi}[c]{1in}{aa}
```

Good, let's go on.

```
% latex.ltx, line 11828:
\long\def\@iiiparbox#1#2[#3]#4#5{%
  \leavevmode
  \@pboxswfalse
  \setlength\@tempdima{#4}%
  \@begin@tempboxa\vbox{\hsize\@tempdima\@parboxrestore#5\@@par}%
    \ifx\relax#2\else
      \setlength\@tempdimb{#2}%
      \edef\@parboxto{to\the\@tempdimb}%
    \fi
    \if#1b\vbox
    \else\if #1t\vtop
    \else\ifmmode\vcenter
    \else\@pboxswtrue $\vcenter
    \fi\fi\fi
    \@parboxto{\let\hss\vss\let\unhbox\unvbox
       \csname bm@#3\endcsname}%
    \if@pboxsw \m@th$\fi
  \@end@tempboxa}
```

This is where the `\parbox` is actually typeset. And the error message you get is

```
! Extra \else.
\@iiiparbox ...tore #5\@@par }\ifx \relax #2\else
                                                  \setlength \@tempdimb {#2}...
```

The various macros we have seen above use `\relax` when the second optional argument is not used, so the final macro can do this test. But with your `#2` you get

```
\ifx\relax\ifnum 5 > 4 \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax\else 20pt\fi
```

and `\ifx` compares `\relax` with `\ifnum`, so this conditional is lost. Start the optional argument with `\empty` instead:

```
\parbox[c][\empty\ifnum 5 > 4 \dimexpr \ccc + \bbb\relax\else 20pt\fi]{1in}{aa}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detail explanation!! An extra `\relax` causes my first case failing to run. And in my example `\ifcase\cond 0\or 1\fi|`, `\relax` is needed. I'm puzzled.